# How to return pattern from 2 integer list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, sorting

**Question:**
I want to return the similarity of pattern from 2 integer list input,

Input example :

6 6

2 3 6 8 10 15

3 8 2 15 3 4

And the output should be:

3

[3, 8, 15]

and here is my code :

**Code:**

```
def main():
  q_element = [] 
  list1=[]
  list2=[]
  
  q_element = [int(item) for item in input("Quantity of each list : ").split()]
  list1 = [int(item) for item in input("Enter list 1    : ").split()]
  list2 =  [int(item) for item in input("enter list 2 : ").split()] 

  result = common_elements(list1, list2)
  if len(result) == 0 :
    return "No pattern"
  else:
    if len(list1) == q_element[0] and len(list2) == q_element[1]:
      print(len(result));
      return result;
    else :
      return "Your input doesn't match the quantity";

def common_elements(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for element in list1:
        if element in list2:
            result.append(element)
    return result

main()
```

**Output:**

```
Quantity of each list : 6 6
Enter list 1    : 2 3 6 8 10 15
enter list 2 : 3 8 2 15 3 4
4
[2, 3, 8, 15]
```

[image: This is the example of the output (the red marker)]

This is the example of the output (the red marker one)

I use the test input from above but the output is still not the same, can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I understand, but a `2` is a member of two lists. That seems like intended behavior, as in, your code works.

Comment: Should `2` be omitted because it appears out of order and `[3, 8, 15]` is the longest in-order sequence shared between the lists?

Comment: Can you define 'similarity of pattern'? It's unclear exactly what you need

Comment: Are you looking for the longest common subsequence between the two lists?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll update the question with the image example

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood your question correctly, but looking at the example you gave you can change the `common_elements` function in the following way:

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for element in list1:
        if element in list2:
            result.append(element)
            list2 = list2[list2.index(element)+1:]
    return result
```